# I want to display contact name and phone number but it fails

Tags: java, android

```
  public class AutocompleteMain extends Activity implements   OnItemClickListener,  OnItemSelectedListener  {

// Initialize variables



AutoCompleteTextView  textView=null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Store contacts values in these arraylist
public static ArrayList<String> phoneValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> nameValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();

EditText toNumber=null;
String toNumberValue="";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_main);

    final Button Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send);

    // Initialize AutoCompleteTextView values

        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.toNumber);

        //Create adapter    
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                  (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<String>());
        textView.setThreshold(1);

       //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        textView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    // Read contact data and add data to ArrayAdapter
    // ArrayAdapter used by AutoCompleteTextView

       readContactData();


   /********** Button Click pass textView object ***********/
    Send.setOnClickListener(BtnAction(textView));


}

private OnClickListener BtnAction(final AutoCompleteTextView toNumber) {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String NameSel = "";
            NameSel = toNumber.getText().toString();


            final String ToNumber = toNumberValue;


            if (ToNumber.length() == 0 ) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please fill phone number",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), NameSel+" : "+toNumberValue,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };
}   


// Read phone contact name and phone numbers 

private void readContactData() {

    try {

        /*********** Reading Contacts Name And Number **********/

        String phoneNumber = "";
        ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext()
                .getContentResolver();

        //Query to get contact name

        Cursor cur = cr
                .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        // If data data found in contacts 
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

            Log.i("AutocompleteContacts", "Reading   contacts........");

            int k=0;
            String name = "";

            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {

                String id = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                //Check contact have phone number
                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur
                                .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                {

                    //Create query to get phone number by contact id
                    Cursor pCur = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?",
                                        new String[] { id },
                                        null);
                        int j=0;

                        while (pCur
                                .moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            // Sometimes get multiple data 
                            if(j==0)
                            {
                                // Get Phone number
                                phoneNumber =""+pCur.getString(pCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                                // Add contacts names to adapter
                                adapter.add(name);

                                // Add ArrayList names to adapter
                                phoneValueArr.add(phoneNumber.toString());
                                nameValueArr.add(name.toString());

                                j++;
                                k++;
                            }
                        }  // End while loop
                        pCur.close();
                    } // End if

            }  // End while loop

        } // End Cursor value check
        cur.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.i("AutocompleteContacts","Exception : "+ e);
    }


    }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "onItemSelected() position " + position);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
            INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Get Array index value for selected name
         int i = nameValueArr.indexOf(""+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));

        // If name exist in name ArrayList
        if (i >= 0) {

            // Get Phone Number
            toNumberValue = phoneValueArr.get(i);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                    INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            // Show Alert       
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Position:"+arg2+" Name:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+" Number:"+toNumberValue,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", 
                        "Position:"+arg2+" Name:"+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)+" Number:"+toNumberValue);

        }

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Actually my goal is to get the contact name and phone number but my code show the output like this **please fill the phone number** which is irritating me so if anybody knows about it let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: where u got stuck in fetching contact from device or in showing in list view

Answer (score 0):

**Activity which shows the name and number in list view...**

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

ListView list;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);

    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, String> nameNumberMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String contactName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        nameNumberMap.put("Name",contactName);
        nameNumberMap.put("Number",contactNumber);
        al.add(nameNumberMap);

    }

    Log.e("check","as2");
    customAdapter adapter = new customAdapter(this, al);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.e("check","as2"+al.size());



}
}
```

**Custom Adapter class**

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public customAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al) {
    Log.e("check", "");
    activity = a;
    this.al = al;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return al.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }
    TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.Number);

    HashMap<String, String> contains = new HashMap<String, String>();
    contains = al.get(position);
    Log.e("value check:----", contains.get("Name"));
    name.setText(contains.get("Name"));
    number.setText(contains.get("Number"));
    return vi;
}

}
```

**XML for first activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML for row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >


    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

**This code is for the search functionality of the contacts**

what I do here is when user goes on typing in the edit text the name contacts are searched from the contacts list and are displayed in the listview below edittext...this is similar to our default contacts search functionality in contacts list or phonebook of our device

```
EditText edit_text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

    edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable changed_text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String search_value=getText(R.id.txtItem).toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), changed_text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            display_list(changed_text.toString(),changed_text.length(), NAME[0]);

        }
    });

}



/** displaying the list of the best match contacts */

public void display_list(final String searchString,int searchStringLength, final String actionTOPerform)
{

     listview =(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

     /** Defining the ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

     adapter.clear();

            try {


                 phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
                 phones.moveToFirst();
                    while(phones.moveToNext())
                    {
                        Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                        if( (Name.toLowerCase()).contains(searchString.toLowerCase()) )
                        {

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }

                    }

                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TODO: handle exception
                }


     /** Setting the adapter to the ListView */
     setListAdapter(adapter);      

     /** Setting up the call on item click from the list */
    OnItemClickListener selectedItem = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View selectedContact, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            String callcontact =  ((TextView)selectedContact).getText().toString();
            phones.moveToFirst();
            while (phones.moveToNext())
          {
            String Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String Number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if(Name.compareToIgnoreCase(callcontact)== 0)
            {


                String url = "tel:"+Number;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));

                startActivity(intent);


            }
        }

        }
    };

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(selectedItem);

}//end of display_list
```

[image: something like this]
[image]

Comment: dear brother thanks for the now would u like to tel me how number and name are prints after adding your code

Comment: you can simply put them in map as key value pairs and print them in List View

Comment: dear would u like to send me the code of printing both contact name and number. thanks

Comment: now that works perfectly fine for me.... first fetch name and numbers and them put them in customized ListView..

Comment: thanks for your above code but  i need a code related to search contacts . after search a particular contact then click on select button and then name and number shown to me of that particular search contact. so can u help me in this plz.

Comment: @user3325090 Yes sure.....this code helps you to fetch and list all the contacts....so if you just want to search and not list all the contacts....you can store the contacts in a hash-map and take a search value from user and search with the keys in has-map

Comment: thanks u soo much dear dixit. now plz would u like to send me the screen shot of the interface where it prints the name and phone number of selected contact plz.  thanks again dear. but just send me the interface screen shot where it prints the name and number . plz don't edit the previous answer

Comment: @user3325090 This code is an extract of my voice dialler application...in which when I click on some contact it dials a call to that contact number directly....if you just want to display it you can call an intent in `public void onItemClick` and pass the values of name and contact via `putExtra` method

Comment: dear dixit would u like to send me the complete code of this project i alse need calling function. so this complete project will be helpful for me. this is my email address sultanmahmood0@gmail.com plz send it here i,m waiting. thanks for the help brother.

Comment: @user3325090 you can download it from [here](https://bitbucket.org/yogeshdixit41/green-voice-dialler/overview)